# Methods of finding the difference to the nearest integer?

Tags: binomial-theorem

The question asked to find the "smallest value of n such that $(1+2^{0.5})^n$ is within 10^-9 of a whole number." I'm unsure of the approach to the question.

The question was in the chapter of 'binomial expansion' in the textbook.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hint: Compare $(1+\sqrt{2})^2$ with $(\sqrt{2}-1)^2$, and $(1+\sqrt{2})^3$ with $(\sqrt{2}-1)^3$.  Expand them out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For such problems, the concept of **conjugated terms** is important.
If you look at the binomial expansion of $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ and $(1-\sqrt{2})^n$ you will see that all the terms including $\sqrt{2}$ in an odd power will have opposite signs. Hence
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n$$ is always an integer.
But fortunately $|1-\sqrt{2}| \approx 0.4<1$ and so the second term quickly converges to 0 which makes $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ getting closer to an integer value.
Now, to estimate how close this is you have to analyse how quick $(1-\sqrt{2})^n$ converges to 0. Can you continue from here?

Comment: thanks! I was able to find the answer (n=24) with your hint. Just wondering, is it possible for the answer to be found without the help of a calculator?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not easily possible. Note that the condition you obtain is $n>-\frac{9\log(10)}{\log (\sqrt{2}-1)} \approx 23.51$. So any "elementary" way would have to make bounds on this number. Of course, this is technically possible but you would have to use really close approximations on the $\log$s to get the exact result.